# Stop related entities to be queried in doctrine2 while using QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am having two entities User and Profile with one to one relationship.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->add('select', 'u')
   ->add('from', '\Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User u')
   ->add('orderBy', 'u.id DESC');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$customer = $query->execute();
```

When i Check the number of queries in Symfony profiler I could see *n* number for queries triggered on Profile table for *n* users in User table. Is there any way where I can stop the querying of the Profile table.

Please let me know if there is better way of implementing it.

Thanks in advance

**Added Entity Classes**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Profile
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $profile;

}

class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $user_id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @var string $user_name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $user_name;

    /**
     * @var Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;    

}
```

**Response from the mysql log**

```
120110 15:14:29    89 Connect   root@localhost on test
           89 Query SET NAMES UTF8
           89 Query SELECT c0_.id AS id0, c0_.email AS email1, c0_.password AS password2, c0_.is_demo_user AS is_demo_user3, c0_.status AS status4, c0_.current_service AS current_service5, c0_.registration_mode AS registration_mode6, c0_.verification_code AS verification_code7, c0_.account_type AS account_type8, c0_.activated_date AS activated_date9, c0_.status_updated_at AS status_updated_at10, c0_.created_at AS created_at11, c0_.updated_at AS updated_at12 FROM user c0_ WHERE c0_.id = 1 ORDER BY c0_.email ASC
           89 Query SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.user_id AS user_id2, t0.user_name AS user_name3, t0.age AS age4, t0.created_at AS created_at5, t0.updated_at AS updated_at6, t0.user_id AS user_id7 FROM profile t0 WHERE t0.user_id = '1'
           89 Quit
```

Comment: Can you post contents of your User entity? Because as far I can understand from the manual http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html this shouldn't happen unless you do a fetch join by specifing both entities to select. Do you use MySQL? Consider to enable mysql general-log en look what is exactly send to the server with tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log (example). Good luck

Comment: Hi Kees Schepers, Thanks for your response, I have added my entity class structure to the question and from the query code which I have added earlier you can know I am not making any join, even if I join the profile table only the query to get users is affected with the join and still the individual queries to fetch profile exists.

Comment: Could you also post the exact queries Doctrine sends to your server? From the general-log? Could you try a unidirectional relationship too? http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: Hi Kees Schepers, Thanks for your response again!, I have added the query from the log.

Comment: Hmm, strange, did u try the unidirection relationship too? Maybe that clears things out..

Comment: yes but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand. According to this documentation: http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/d2.html#joins your DQL query should work and not fetch records from the profile table.. Which version of Doctrine are you using? And why are you calling $query->execute() instead of something like $query->getArrayResult()? Could you try that last one? You could try the #doctrine IRC channel to.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here!!

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

"In many cases associations between entities can get pretty large. Even in a simple scenario like a blog. where posts can be commented, you always have to assume that a post draws hundrets of comments. In Doctrine 2.0 if you accessed an association it would always get loaded completly into memory. This can lead to pretty serious performance problems, if your associations contain several hundrets or thousands of entities.

With Doctrine 2.1 a feature called Extra Lazy is introduced for associations. Associations are marked as Lazy by default, which means the whole collection object for an association is populated the first time its accessed. If you mark an association as extra lazy the following methods on collections can be called without triggering a full load of the collection:"

```
<?php
namespace Doctrine\Tests\Models\CMS;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class CmsGroup
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="CmsUser", mappedBy="groups", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
    */
    public $users;
}
```

It's a bit late, but it might help others out there!

Comment: Hi thingygeoff, thank you for the answer, but Extra Lazy keyword works only on many to many relationsip